# jQuery: How to get the style attribute for "position" of an element?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

What is the proper mark-up in jQuery (or JavaScript) to get the style attribute "position" for an element in the DOM?

Example:

#### HTML

```
<div id="Parent">
    Parent Element
    <ul class="child">
        <li>
            <p>inner child elements</p>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

#### CSS

```
#Parent {
    position: relative;
}
.child {
    position: absolute;
}
```

#### JavaScript:

```
$(function() {
    //  What to type here to get "style attribute position" of say #Parent?
})
```

Comment: Yes, there is. Have you tried anything?

Comment: Yes, I tried but somehow missed the solution. Thanks for help.

Comment: @JamesMontagne I wouldn't say duplicate just simply because of the jQuery reference

Comment: It seems a reasonable question to me as the jQuery `position()` is unrelated and also some css values have specific functions.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
$('#someElementID').css('position');
```

http://api.jquery.com/css/

Answer (score 2):

Use this, in jQuery:

```
$(element).css("position");
```

And more:

```
$(element).offset();
$(element).offset().top;
$(element).offset().left;
```

Comment: might as well include [.position()](http://api.jquery.com/position/) reference.

Comment: The `position()` function is completely unrelated to the css value of 'position'.

Comment: @nicodemus13 Well, it has been like an year since this was answered. Why are you digging the post? `:)`

Comment: Just a note, as I assumed the jQuery position function was about the css position, not the position in the window... others may think this too :)

Comment: It is the CSS `position` property, that has values like `absolute`, `relative`, `static`, `fixed`, etc.